# Grunt Plugin for Debug, Test and Release Conditions

Tags: javascript, debugging, gruntjs, release

Is there a Grunt Plugin where I can write in my Files (e.g. *.js Files) something link

```
#if DEBUG 
var apiAddress = "http://localhost:8080/api";
#elif RELEASE
var apiAddress = "http://mywebsite.com/api";
#endif
```

so when I run

```
grunt serve
```

The variable should be *http://localhost:8080/api*

but if I run

```
grunt build
```

The variable should be *http://mywebsite.com/api*, the *#if DEBUG*-Part should be deleted

Comment: Try using https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-text-replace

Comment: Ah thank you! I'm corious why there is not more in the internet about this subject. Am I the only who ran in this problem? Or how do you solve this, when you want to link your UI to your Debug-/Test-API or use a different Database Connection when you're Debugging?